Dropbox Sign API - Create Template API Error
I have been trying to create a new Dropbox Sign Template using Dropbox Sign Create Template API.
Please see the C# code snippet below.
string content = "{\"client_id\":\"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\",\"file_urls\":[\"https://www.dropbox.com/s/ad9qnhbrjjn64tu/mutual-NDA-example.pdf?dl=1\"],\"title\":\"DocuSign_Template_001\",\"subject\":\"Complete with Docusign\",\"message\":\"Complete\",\"signer_roles\":[{\"name\":\"Meghan\",\"order\":0}],\"cc_roles\":null,\"merge_fields\":null,\"field_options\":null,\"form_fields_per_document\":[{\"document_index\":0,\"api_id\":\"11c7e79e-168b-4548-ad64-0c64e4a16ace\",\"name\":\"\",\"type\":\"signature\",\"x\":714,\"y\":57,\"width\":120,\"height\":30,\"required\":true,\"signer\":0,\"page\":1}],\"test_mode\":true}";

var requestContent = new StringContent(content, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
var response = await client.PostAsync("https://api.hellosign.com/v3/template/create", requestContent);

if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); 
}
else
{
    string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    //{"error":{"error_msg":"form fields are required","error_path":"form_fields_per_document","error_name":"bad_request"}}
}                            

The Create Template request fails with Status Code 400 and the following error message in response.
{"error":{"error_msg":"form fields are required","error_path":"form_fields_per_document","error_name":"bad_request"}}
I have set the form fields in the json as described in the documentation below:
https://developers.hellosign.com/api/reference/operation/templateCreate/
I do not want to use Dropbox Sign .NET SDK as it supports version >= .Net 6.0.
Can someone please guide me how to fix this error.
Thanks!

Try sending the default example and see if it works.  Then modify example to meet your needs.

Dropbox Support suggested to use the following Dictionary<string, string> collection. This created a new Dropbox Sign Template
  using (var client = new HttpClient())
  {
      client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new 
      AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", this.AccessToken);
      var data = new Dictionary<string, string>
                        {
                                { "client_id","XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"},
                                { "form_fields_per_document[0][document_index]", "0"},
                                { "form_fields_per_document[0][type]", "signature"},
                                { "form_fields_per_document[0][api_id]", "sign_1"},
                                { "form_fields_per_document[0][name]", ""},
                                { "form_fields_per_document[0][height]", "60"},
                                { "form_fields_per_document[0][width]", "220"},
                                { "form_fields_per_document[0][x]", "230"},
                                { "form_fields_per_document[0][y]", "15"},
                                { "form_fields_per_document[0][required]", "true"},
                                { "form_fields_per_document[0][page]", "1"},
                                { "form_fields_per_document[0][signer]", "0"},
                                { "file_urls[0]", "https://www.dropbox.com/s/ad9qnhbrjjn64tu/mutual-NDA-example.pdf?dl=1"},
                                { "signer_roles[0][name]", "Client"},
                                { "signer_roles[0][order]", "0"},
                                { "signer_roles[1][name]", "Witness"},
                                { "signer_roles[1][order]", "1"},
                                { "cc_roles[0]", "Manager"},                     
                                { "title",  "DocuSign_Template_006"},
                                { "subject", "Please sign this document" },
                                { "message", "For your approval" },
                                { "test_mode", "true"}
                        };  

                            FormUrlEncodedContent requestContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(data);
                            var response = await client.PostAsync("https://api.hellosign.com/v3/template/create", requestContent);
}

